# docker-compose up throwing error ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', service must be a mapping, not a NoneType

Tags: docker, redis, yaml, alpine-linux

```yaml
version: '3'
services :
web :

  build:
  ports:
  - "5000:5000"
  redis:
  image:"redis:alpine"
```

when executing the docker-compose up it throws an error:
ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', service must be a mapping, not a NoneType

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you put `web:` on the same level as `services:`. It needs to be more indented. Also, `redis:` needs to be on the same level as `web:` and you need a space after `image:`.

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
    ports:
    - "5000:5000"
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

Comment: i tried that but i see a new error :ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.web.ports contains an invalid type, it should be an array
services.web.build contains an invalid type, it should be a string, or an object

Comment: Well you need to provide a value for `build:` which you currently don't. It's not required so simply remove it if you don't want to supply a value. The error about `ports:` looks like you're using a different YAML than I posted, since that *does* contain a sequence (which will be loaded into an array).